# Find regex match without a digit preceding the pattern

Tags: python, regex, match, digits

I am currently trying to extract dates from strings. Here are a few examples:

```
02.10 abcdef -> extract '02.10'
abcdef 03.12 -> extract '03.12'
abcdef 308.56 -> extract nothing
```

A simple regex such as `(\d{2}.\d{2})` works fine for the first two cases but I catch a false positive for the third example, the regex returns `08.56`, which makes sense.

Is there any way to prevent this string from being extracted? I tried `[^0-9](\d{2}.\d{2})` which seems to be working on regex debugging websites but not when I compile it as a python regex with

```
import re
regex = re.compile(r'[^0-9](\d{2}.\d{2})')
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Note that a `.` in regex is a wildcard and should be escaped if you want to match a `.` Otherwise you are just matching any character that follows `d{2}`

Comment: You can use word boundaries on the left and right and escape the dot `\b\d{2}\.\d{2}\b`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I First thought you needed the complete number which is possible with:
`(\d*\.\d{2})` which returns 308.56

But then is saw the line:

> Is there any way to prevent this string from being extracted?
> Which made me expect you want only two numbers, a dot and again two numbers. Otherwise the regex should return nothing.

Then the answer should be:

```
(?<![\w\d])(\d{2}\.\d{2})(?![\w\d])
```

You can test it on https://regex101.com/

[image]

Comment: Note that `\w` also matches `\d`